Data Storage Volume (e.g. HDD) - physical representation, volume and file system
My primary questions are: what exactly is a volume on a byte level, as opposed to partition or file system? What does it look like in binary? Can I open an HDD (raw) and find volume data structure just like I can find partition table or a filesystem? Or is it a structure in OS kernel RAM? Is the concept of "drive volume" OS-specific?

EDIT
Maybe a reformulated and more specific question will help, feel free to correct me:
Partition table is a collection of values at a few specific locations. They have certain meanings. Partitions are slices of storage that can be treated as separate entities, and they're listed in block 0 or block 1 (sometimes further) inside the device. They physically exist there. What is a volume in that sense? Is it some kind of structure inside OS kernel, or is it saved somewhere on the drive and I can see it if I read raw drive data?

Orig post cont.
I have searched the internet inside and out in different languages for many days, but all I got was vague abstract words and pictures. Very pretty, not very useful for anything related to data recovery, which I'm interested in. I'm interested in raw data. I want to open the drive as a series of bits/bytes (or in a hex editor), point my finger and say "this is the volume".
Partitions are all nice and (relatively) simple. I have a storage device, it has blocks of memory. A partition table is just a list of contiguous parts of the drive. Blocks 10-200 are one partition, blocks 201-400 are another partition. Pretty simple. Volumes are abstract though. When I look for specifics, I find nothing (that would satisfy me).
Instead, all I get is something like this picture, that shows up in every other article on the matter (source):

Perfect example of "pretty, but useless". It shows logical relation between things, but only prompts more questions. For example, what is the the white block outside the volume? Why is it outside the volume and not inside it? Does it mean, the file system only manages
what is inside the volume, while the rest stays unused?
As far as I gathered, volume is a part of a partition managed by a single file system. At least in basic cases. (You are encounraged to correct this statement). At the same time, I see mentions of volume spanning more than one partition in some file systems. If file system is so tied with the concept of volume, why use the concept of volume at all. In the picture, there is one partition split into two volumes, I would suspect calling it all a collection of file systems rather than a collection of volumes would be (near?) equivalent.
Does "volume" have physical representation? Does it live in OS kernel? Or on the drive? Why is this level of abstraction even necessary? Do volumes work like partitions inside partition?

Not referring to any specific article. Question: what does the volume look like on a byte level?

so you have to understand that spinning media is inherently analog, and things like blocks are an abstraction on top of an abstraction on top of an abstraction. Look into Sectors/Cylinders/Heads to start understanding how the disk hardware actually stores analog signal on the disk. then you can start looking into digital abstractions like blocks.

Okay, let's say I care only about SSD then. Interested in soft level for now.


My primary questions are: what exactly is a volume on a byte level, as opposed to partition or file system?

A volume consists of two things, a directory and storage space(s). The collection of storage spaces of a volume can be located on a variety of hard disks. The most simple volume is a partition, that is referring to just one continuous space on one disk. Volume management in an operating system enables a higher level in the storage management to adress all n sectors of a volume by a number from 0 to n-1 disregarding the absolute sector address on different physical locations (harddisks).
To provide this kind of service for the quoted "higher level in the storage management" running a volume that is bigger than just one partition on a disk requires some kind of directory which stores the locations of the storage spaces.
Example (simplified)
Directory:
There is Volume v1 and it has a total length of 9 sectors.
disk one: location sector 77, 2 sectors, representing sectors 3 and 4
disk two: location sector 342, 3 sectors, representing sectors 0 to 2
disk three: location sector 25, 5 sectors, representing sectors 5 to
8
If the higher layer of the operating system would like to read the sector 6 of volume v1, the lower layer has to check the directory to find the location. In this example sector 6 is stored on disk three on sector 26.
The lower level would then return the content of sector 26 on disk three.
The higher level does not have to take care of where the single storage areas that compose the volume are physically located.
From a logical viewpoint, a partition is just a special case of a volume consisting of just one storage space.
Both the old MBR partition table structure and the new GPT one provide all necessary information to address the content of a partition.
There is no other directory necessary.
From a historical viewpoint, a volume is an extension of the old school partition, enabling combining partitions into larger ones, called volumes.
An average user is only dealing with partitions or differently said with volumes that contain just one storage space - the content of the partition.
When dealing practically with volumes, the space of a volume is being fully occupied by a file system by means of formating the volume.
In addition to that in an Microsoft environment the volume is typically assigned a volume label. In linux, formatted volume space is typically mounted somewhere in the directory tree.

What does it look like in binary?

The binary representation of the volume concept varies depending on the operating system. In a Microsoft environment one is confronted with the old "dynamic disk" concept or the modern "storage spaces".
In the linux world there is a kind of Microsoft emulation for dynamic disks available, called LDM ("logical device manager"). Linux has its own volume concept implemented by the LVM ("logical volume manager").

Can I open an HDD (raw) and find volume data structure just like I can find partition table or a filesystem?

Generally no, but if the volumes are only limited to the use of one partition you can interpret the partition table to learn about the volumes.
Otherwise you have to gather directory information to learn about the whole structure. By evaluating the partition table you might sometimes be able to learn that the partitions listed are part of a bigger volume.
Finding the beginning of file system by scanning a harddisk in a linear manner will might not necessary tell you that you just only found a piece of a bigger entity.

Or is it a structure in OS kernel RAM?

As its structure has to be kept permanently, it may sometimes be buffered in RAM but is most likely to be found in configuration files, in an Microsoft environment it might be located in the registry.

Is the concept of "drive volume" OS-specific?

Yes.


As far as I gathered, volume is a part of a partition managed by a
single file system. At least in basic cases. (You are encounraged to
correct this statement). At the same time, I see mentions of volume
spanning more than one partition in some file systems. If file system
is so tied with the concept of volume, why use the concept of volume
at all. In the picture, there is one partition split into two volumes,
I would suspect calling it all a collection of file systems rather
than a collection of volumes would be (near?) equivalent.
Does "volume" have physical representation? Does it live in OS kernel?
Or on the drive? Why is this level of abstraction even necessary? Do
volumes work like partitions inside partition?

ok, so I'm going to offer this as a simple alternative to the other answers, by sticking to the definition of a "volume".
All the things you have learned and are learning have value, but you are making this way too complicated. which is kinda the point of the term.
A "Volume" is a unit of secondary data storage that an OS can address. That is literally it. End-of-definition.
The reason I point this out, is that the term "volume" is used to abstract away all the details of the underlying data storage and access mechanisms, and highlight how they are all the same by the time they are presented to the user.
The term does not care what physical media form it takes (HDD, SSD, USB, SDC, CD/DVD, etc). It also doesn't matter what internal data structures it has (Partitions, RAID, RAW, ISO-9660, etc), or what protocols it uses (IDE/SCSI/SATA/SAS, NVMe, fibre HBA + LUN, iSCSI, SMB/NFS/SSHFS, etc).
The term "Volume" is used precisely because it implies NONE of these technologies explicitly.
You are spending a lot of focus worrying about how a volume is implemented using specific stacks of devices+protocols+software with which you are familiar, but that is antithetical to the actual use/usefulness of the term.
hope that helps

A unit of secondary data storage? What does the word "secondary" mean in this context? And what is primary storage then? Never heard of storage being primary or secondary, so if you could specify that part, it would help.

in modern computer architectures, Primary storage is RAM + CPU Cache: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/primstor.htm
